# Additional code only for certain lang on multi language site

Tags: 2013-sp1, blueprint

We have a client with a multi language site, where the client requests for certain set of functionalities only for certain languages. They want to try out some language sites before rolling out globally. We only have one deploy and blue print layers takes care of other language websites. Is there any option in Tridion, just to enable and disable certain functionality of the website in configurable way? Reason I am asking is to try and do with minimal code changes. 
I am new to Tridion CMS, so anything not a proper understanding excuse with it.
Thanks,
Rams

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site, your question is very unclear to me, and that might be because you are new to Tridion, but I also think you seem to assume we know exactly how your implementation is done, which we don't. I suggest you **edit** your question and supply some more detail into what BluePrint you are using for example, and what exactly you need, so that you can get an appropriate answer. Think about explaining your question to us like you would need to explain it to a rubber ducky (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Hi Rams, welcome! I agree with Bart. Some of the things we really need to know: is you site using DXA or DD4T or are you using another implementation technic?

Answer (score 4):

We have used components from Tridion on the web app side to get some configuration to enable/disable features. We call them configuration components. The schema is very simple which allows capturing key-value information and it is a dynamic component so that you can publish it independently. The component's key-value pairs determine whether we turn on-off any features (without code deployment on the web app) for the end customer on the website. So, when we need a change, just change the value in the component and publish.

The web app calls this component on app start and periodically refresh it (any interval you desire) by making an odata call for the component and then cache it in memory. You can also implement an event based cache clearing mechanism (like on every publish) for the component which is going to be more complex, but for our scenario a periodic refresh was fine.